# How to reference a plain object in another file with JSdoc?

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I want to reference a variable to a plain object from another file via JSDoc to use IDE autocomplete.

Here is my example:

**MySample.js**

```
export const MySample = {
  findMe() {
    return "Hi!";
  },
};

export default MySample;
```

**index.js**

```
import MySample from "./MySample.js";

let window = {};
function inject($key, $object) {
  window[$key] = $object;
}

inject("MySample", MySample);

let my_sample = window.MySample;

console.log(my_sample.findMe());
```

I tried to use something like the following, but it was not successful:

```
/**
 * @type {import('./MySample').MySample} my_sample
 */
```

P.S: I know if `My Sample` be a class, the above solution is working. But in my scenario I want to reference a plain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as follows:

```
/**
 * @param {import('./MySample').MySample} my_sample
 */
inject("MySample", MySample);
```

The key is using [`@param`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) instead of [`@type`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html)